The ImagePIcker is not working in my Flutter app
I used image_picker package in my project. But it is not working. I picked an image, but the image is not showing in the container. There is no issue in the code, but after I picked an image, only Error message is printing. Pls look at my code and please guide me the right path that how I can solve. Below is my code from 2 separate files. I want the photo to be shown after picked an image.
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:rootine/api/api-services.dart';
import 'package:rootine/components/profile_create_update_components/image_uploader.dart';
import 'package:rootine/widget_styles.dart';

class CreatePlantProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String routeId = 'addPlantDetails';

  final String idToken;
  const CreatePlantProfile({super.key, required this.idToken});

  @override
  State<CreatePlantProfile> createState() => _CreatePlantProfileState();
}

class _CreatePlantProfileState extends State<CreatePlantProfile> {
  TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _speciesController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _ageController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _noteController = TextEditingController();

  File? _image;
  String? nameValue;
  String? locationValue;
  String? speciesValue;
  String? plantAge;
  String? noteValue;

  final List<String> locations = ['Indoor', 'Outdoor'];

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      final bytes = await image.readAsBytes();
      setState(() {
        _image = bytes.buffer.asUint8List() as File?;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _createPlantProfile() async {
    print('Image: $_image');
    print('Name: $nameValue');
    print('Location: $locationValue');
    print('Species: $speciesValue');
    print('Plant Age: $plantAge');
    print('Notes: $noteValue');

    // ApiService apiService = ApiService();
    // try {
    //   await apiService.createPlantProfile(
    //     idToken: widget.idToken,
    //     plantName: _nameController.text,
    //     species: _speciesController.text,
    //     plantingDate: _ageController.text,
    //     location: locationValue!,
    //     notes: _noteController.text,
    //     photo: _image,
    //   );
    //   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Plant profile created successfully')));
    // } catch (e) {
    //   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())));
    // }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 1000,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                //ImageUploading Section
                ImageUploader(
                  imageDefaultPath: 'assets/images/default_image.png',
                  selectedImage: _image,
                  pickedImage: getImage,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22, vertical: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Add Plant Details',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color(0xff5B7A49)),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 350,
                          child: ListView(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 19,
                            ),
                            children: [
                              //Name
                              ListTile(
                                title: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.keyboard_alt_outlined,
                                      size: 16,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Text(
                                      'Name',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff436132)),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: Container(
                                  width: 170,
                                  height: 24,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffE8E8E8)),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    style: kDetailTextFieldTextStyle,
                                    showCursor: false,
                                    decoration: kDetailTextFieldDecoration,
                                    controller: _nameController,
                                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                      nameValue = newValue;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Plant Location Type
                              ListTile(
                                title: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.location_on_outlined,
                                      size: 16,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Text(
                                      'Location',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff436132)),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: Container(
                                  width: 170,
                                  height: 24,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffE8E8E8)),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: DropdownButton(
                                      isExpanded: true,
                                      items: locations.map((String location) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem(value: location, child: Text(location));
                                      }).toList(),
                                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          locationValue = newValue;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      value: locationValue,
                                      icon: kRootineDropdownIcon,
                                      borderRadius: kRootineDropdownButtonBorderRadius,
                                      style: kRootineDropDownButtonTextStyle,
                                      underline: Container(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Species
                              ListTile(
                                title: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.eco_outlined,
                                      size: 16,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Text(
                                      'Species',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff436132)),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: Container(
                                  width: 170,
                                  height: 24,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffE8E8E8)),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    style: kDetailTextFieldTextStyle,
                                    showCursor: false,
                                    decoration: kDetailTextFieldDecoration,
                                    controller: _speciesController,
                                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                      speciesValue = newValue;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Plant Age
                              ListTile(
                                title: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                                      size: 16,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Text(
                                      'Plant age',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff436132)),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: Container(
                                  width: 170,
                                  height: 24,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffE8E8E8)),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    style: kDetailTextFieldTextStyle,
                                    showCursor: false,
                                    decoration: kDetailTextFieldDecoration,
                                    controller: _ageController,
                                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                      plantAge = newValue;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Plant note
                              ListTile(
                                titleAlignment: ListTileTitleAlignment.top,
                                title: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.sticky_note_2_outlined,
                                      size: 16,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Text(
                                      'Note',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff436132)),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: Container(
                                  width: 170,
                                  height: 90,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffE8E8E8)),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    minLines: 1,
                                    maxLines: 10,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                                    showCursor: false,
                                    decoration: kDetailTextFieldDecoration,
                                    controller: _noteController,
                                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                      noteValue = newValue;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff75A081),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            ),
                            onPressed: _createPlantProfile,
                            child: Text(
                              'Save',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageUploader extends StatelessWidget {
  String? imageDefaultPath;
  File? selectedImage;
  Function pickedImage;

  ImageUploader({required this.selectedImage, required this.pickedImage, this.imageDefaultPath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 262,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            image: selectedImage != null
                ? DecorationImage(
                    image: kIsWeb ? NetworkImage(selectedImage!.path) : FileImage(File(selectedImage!.path)) as ImageProvider,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                : DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(imageDefaultPath!),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 41,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(125, 0, 0, 0)),
            child: IconButton(
              splashRadius: 1,
              onPressed: () {
                pickedImage();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.file_upload_outlined,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Correct your parameters like below,
               ImageUploader(
                  selectedImage: _image,
                  pickedImage: getImage,
                  imageDefaultPath: 'assets/images/default_image.png',
                ), 

As your constructor is...
 ImageUploader({required this.selectedImage, required this.pickedImage, this.imageDefaultPath});

